# Writing a proxyfier application with python

Tags: python, proxy

I'm new to coding in Python and what motivates me to start coding is the idea of writing a piece of software that will connect to a proxy server via SSH and then once connected will route all network traffic of the system trough it, seamlessly to the user.

I am actually using the paramiko module to connect to the server and it works fine, but now I would like to know if there is some way to make the system change its socks proxy configuration so I can route the traffic to the proxy, on a way the user doesn't need to do anything. Is there any existing module that will help on this task ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the existing project [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle), it transfers all traffic over ssh.